# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '014051452X' to data type int

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

```
public void book_copies_table_clicked(){
        try { 
            dtm1.setRowCount(0);
            int row = dc.book_search_table.getSelectedRow();
            Statement s2 = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = s2.executeQuery("select branch_id, copies from book_copies where book_id="+dc.book_search_table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            while(rs1.next()){
                int branchID = rs1.getInt(1);
                String branchID1 = Integer.toString(branchID);
                int copies = rs1.getInt(2);
                String copies1 = Integer.toString(copies);
                dtm1.addRow(new String[] {branchID1,copies1});
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(implementation_class.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

That is the function that will be fired when ever i click on a row in other table. it is working but i keep on getting exceptions like:

```
Oct 25, 2014 8:03:31 PM library_management.implementation_class book_copies_table_clicked
SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '014051452X' to data type int.
```

and many more lines of it. Iam no where converting any stuff from string to int or so. But i still end up getting these.

The book_copies table has 3 columns. book_id :varchar ; branch_id :smallint ; copies :smallint

i tried putting a print message in the catch block of the function and that got printed meaning it is catching an exception but i dont know why.

Comment: that is stored as a varchar(10) in my db

Comment: well, somewhere, whether you realise or not there is an int conversion taking place. start there....

Comment: iam getting the exception while getting out of the function. all the data is being printed perfectly. there are 5 branches and the while loop is looping 5 times perfectly. 014051452X is the book id and it is stored as varchar. iam just using it in the query to retrieve the branches and number of copies of that book. iam doing conversions on the branch id's and copies since they are smallint.

Comment: got it answer is "select branch_id, copies from book_copies where book_id='"+dc.book_search_table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()+"'" . mistake was I FOR GOT ' '. Is a varchar so i have to use '' while comparing